# Не получается удалить базу данных sqlite из Java

Tags: java, sqlite

Как из Java приложения удалить файл базы данных? Соединение с базой закрыто, почему файл остаётся.

```
File file1 = new File("X:\\xxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxx\\xxxxxx\\xxxxxxx\\database.db");
if (file1.delete()) {
    System.out.println(file1.getName() + " is deleted!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
}
```

Comment: Используйте `Files.delete(file1.toPath())`. Этот способ выбрасывает эксепшен и станет понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: покажите как открываете и как закрываете БД.

Comment: Просто в некоторых API количество `open()` должно быть равно количеству `close()` - поэтому не исключаю, что у вас БД не закрывается...

Comment: Я проверял с помощью `con.isClosed()`. Пишет, что соединение закрыто. Вставил в код `Files.delete(file1.toPath())`.Выбрасывается исключение `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: X:\\xxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxx\\xxxxxx\\xxxxxxx\\database.db: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как  этот файл занят другим процессом.`